# Is it possible to make this menu with only UL/LI and CSS?

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to make a menu for my website, and I need only UL and LI for the SEO. It should looks such as :

```
<ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
    <li>Link 5</li>
    <li>Link 6</li>
</ul>
```

I must have 1 link for each li. Horizontal.
It must be dynamic: if I change the text of the Links, it must adjust itself automatically (so in theory no one fixed width should be used on `<li>`).

[image]

[This](http://oi48.tinypic.com/wipn2p.jpg) is (more or less) how the layout should be. More or less because I haven't calculate the real distance between the maximun lenght size for each block of the pair links. Let's say, 20 px left for each block.

As you can see, the distance between the block of links (where there is the 1px border) is different, due to the container (so, the lenght of each pair of links).
I can't use different elements inside the `ul` different of `li`, this is the main problem.

Any idea if this is possible? I tried many ways, but I really don't know how can I get it (and this is the first menu that I don't know how to make it).

Any input would be nice...

Comment: Do you need a fixed number of columns?

Comment: Uhm, this doesnt matter so much now! Anyway, Let's say 3 :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS.

```
li { float: left; display: block; }
```

Here is the jQuery solution : http://jsfiddle.net/ADtke/5/

Comment: I must have 1 links for li! So if the links size is different, I can't have the same vertical border for the ones over and down. Do you mean what I say?

Comment: ok you want the top line and the bottom line to have the same width so they are aligned and have a vertical line on both?

Comment: did you see the picture? It shows what I want. Just notice : the first li (with link Text1) have different width rather than the 3° (Text Very Very large), but the above li's borders is aligned with them...

Comment: Also, notice that I says "dynamic", so no one fixed width should be used on <li> :)

Comment: You do not want to have 2 a tags or links within one li? If you absolutely don't want 2 links in one li, then I can write up a small jquery script to take the width of the longest item. Also I would need to know how many links in each line.

Comment: No, I absolutly don't want 2 links in one li. I know how to do it with jquery, but I need to use only CSS! That's the real challenge :) About number of links in each row, let's say 3, as I wrote to @rainecc.

Comment: so, there isn't any solution?

Comment: I cannot seem to find anything with a better outcome then the jQuery example I provided above. Maybe another Stacker can provide a CSS response. Unfortunately I cant see a solution. Sorry about that. Good luck with your website!

Answer (score 0):

There is a pure CSS3 way, in supported browsers (shame we have this mess of -webkit, -moz)

```
ul { 
  border-left:2px solid #cc0;
  border-right:2px solid #cc0;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 5px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 5px;
  -webkit-column-rule-color: #cc0;
  -webkit-column-rule-style: solid;
  -webkit-column-rule-width: 2px;
  -moz-column-rule-color: #cc0;
  -moz-column-rule-style: solid;
  -moz-column-rule-width: 2px;
  column-rule-color: #cc0;
  column-rule-style: solid;
  column-rule-width: 2px;
}
li {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

​
As in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hyxxJ/5/

Comment: 3 fixed columns, no wrap. If the text is too long, yes, it hides the overflow. Take off the "nowrap" if this behaviour does not suit.

Comment: No! It is not what I ask. Your column width is the same. I need the shortest width for each column...